# Angular FormGroup is becoming invalid on ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

I have a system running on Angular 7.2.0.

On the ngOnInit, I'm initializing the FormGroup like this:

```
this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
  email: this.fb.control(this.user.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  phone: this.fb.control(this.user.phone, [Validators.required]),
  emailNotification: this.fb.control(this.user.emailNotification),
  smsNotification: this.fb.control(this.user.smsNotification),
  profileImage: null,
  signatureImage: null
})
```

Right after this, I add a `console.log`:

```
console.log('ngOnInit', this.profileForm.invalid)
```

It shows `false`. What is correct, because the `this.user` has all the valid values.

However, on ngAfterViewInit I put this log:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.profileForm.invalid)
  }
```

It shows `true`, like the `profileForm` is now invalid. How? Why?

Then, my submit button becomes disabled.

```
<button class="btn btn-blue pull-right" type="submit"  [disabled]="profileForm.invalid">Save</button>
```

I'm sure it was working before. Now it's not working anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Your code works, I make a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vw4xzr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo. I found the problem I will describe below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It was related to the phone's mask.

In my country, landlines have 10 digits and cellphones have 11 digits.

So, my phone input is like this:

```
<input type="tel" class="form-control" mask='{{phoneMask}}' formControlName="phone" placeholder="99 9999 9999" (keypress)="onPhoneKeyPress()">
```

The `phoneMask` changes according to the number of digits. If the user types only 10 digits, the mask is 00 0000 0000. But if the user types 11 digits, the mask is 00 0 0000 0000.

The `profileForm` was becoming invalid because I was starting the `phoneMask` with 00 0000 0000. But the `user.phone` had 11 digits.

So I only had to check it and change the mask before creating the `profileForm`.

```
if (this.user.phone && this.user.phone.length === 11) {
  this.phoneMask = '00 0 0000 0000'
}
```

It fixed my problem. Hope it helps someone else.

BTW, the mask comes from [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask).